# How do you change the TabBar Icon selected color in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

A thorough search of SO is drawing up blanks for this issue.

All the previous answers recommend using `setSelectedImageTintColor` which has since been deprecated.

How can you change the color of your UITabBar Button Icon's/Item's when selected?

Comment: [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *itemArray = self.tabBar.items;

UITabBarItem *item0 =  [itemArray firstObject];

item0.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tap_home_button"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

item0.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tap_home_button_hightlighed"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```